# Flutter start over after user click back button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have issue with app I am creating which loose the current page after user out of the app by clicking back button. even though, the user didn't clear his phone cache.

any suggestion on how to handle this?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( 
            theme: ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              primaryColor: Colors.red,
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
            ),
            home: new SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
   @override
  void initState() {  
   Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () { 
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
   });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SplashScreenContainer();
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
              ModalRoute.withName("/Home"));
          },
          child: Text("Login"),
      );
  }
}


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeBase();
  }
}
```

when user at homePage then click back button. he will be out of the app. then when he open again it takes him to splash screen

Comment: can u provide more information cause i think u should have store cache using shared preference right ?

Comment: I am not implementing sharedpreference. how to handle it using sharedpreference?

Comment: more info plz may be some code :)